# Explanation/documentation of leiningen's defproject macro

Tags: macros, clojure, leiningen

Leiningen's [defproject macro](http://clojuredocs.org/leiningen/leiningen.core/defproject) is an important part of Clojure projects.  However, information/documentation about it seems to be very sparse.

**What are all of the options that `defproject` supports, and what are they used for?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK the sample [project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj) shows all the available configuration options, all with a usage description.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to get the information when the documentation is [in the source code](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/9791484a9be46005c39cf3e51be44cad497b5586/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L439) of the `defproject` macro.